# Suspect suggested edit by anonymous user: what to do?

Tags: discussion

Today I came across [this suggested edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39134#./39134?&_suid=1400508548897040188259327664943) from an anonymous user. The edit added a schematic to a question that was begging for one. At first I found that suspicious: how could an anonymous user know what circuit the OP was talking about, but then I studied the circuit a little and thought that the circuit was ok and the anonymous user was just being helpful. Then I saw that PeterJ rejected it, so I thought that maybe I had been fooled.

My questions:

1. As a reviewer, how should I handle this and similar cases?
2. Should we just go in and rollback the edit (it's been approved now)?

Comment: It's always hard to know with those ones. Looks like the rollback part has answered itself though, the OP has added nomenclature that matches the diagram although mentioned it doesn't match exactly so at this stage it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the OP was using another computer and didn't log in, or didn't understand that logging in was necessary to make the edit appear to be from the same user. In a case like what you saw, I would leave a comment for the OP asking if the added schematic is correct.

On the other hand, if you find a suggested edit that is clearly not correct, roll it back or flag it. I think anonymous or new users' edits to questions should be fairly minor until they've become trusted through reputation gain.

Comment: Agree. Thanks for the answer!